# How to Create Count Columns for Many Variables in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks something like this. Each event has 1-3 tags, that have colors listed in them. All the colors can occur in any of the 3 tag columns. An item can have more than one event.

```
> data.frame(item = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5), event = seq(1,8), 
+            tag1 = c("red","red","blue","green","red","yellow","black","purple"), 
+            tag2 = c("blue","NA","NA","yellow","orange","NA","purple","red"), 
+            tag3 = c("NA","NA","NA","red","magenta","NA","red","green"))
  item event   tag1   tag2    tag3
1    1     1    red   blue      NA
2    1     2    red     NA      NA
3    2     3   blue     NA      NA
4    3     4  green yellow     red
5    4     5    red orange magenta
6    4     6 yellow     NA      NA
7    4     7  black purple     red
8    5     8 purple    red   green
```

What I want to do is transform the data so that I have a row for each item, and then, a column for each possible color, with the value being whether or not that item was ever tagged with it.

For example:

```
| Item| Red | Blue | Green | etc |
| 1   | 1   | 1    | 0     | 0   |
| 2   | 0   | 0    | 1     | 0   |
```

I don't want to have to make the columns manually, because in my actual code, there are about 800 different "colors."

I am working with tidyverse to try and fix this, but am open to other packages that make it easier.

Runtime does matter, as I have more than 10 million events in the dataset.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  na_if("NA") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("tag")) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  count(item, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, 
              values_from = n, 
              values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 5 × 9
   item  blue   red green yellow black magenta orange purple
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1     1     2     0      0     0       0      0      0
2     2     1     0     0      0     0       0      0      0
3     3     0     1     1      1     0       0      0      0
4     4     0     2     0      1     1       1      1      1
5     5     0     1     1      0     0       0      0      1
```

Requests:

```
df %>%
  na_if("NA") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("tag")) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  count(item, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, 
              values_from = n, 
              values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(grey = 0, 
         white = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you!! One quick update - is there an easy modification if I need to have several columns (say "gray", and "white") that don't appear in the data at all for this subset, but basically need to have zeros all the day down for items 1-5?

Comment: @haley Yes, by `mutate()`. Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Using `table` from `base R`

```
table(df1$item[row(df1[-c(1:2)])], unlist(df1[-(1:2)]))
```

-output

```
    black blue green magenta orange purple red yellow
  1     0    1     0       0      0      0   2      0
  2     0    1     0       0      0      0   0      0
  3     0    0     1       0      0      0   1      1
  4     1    0     0       1      1      1   2      1
  5     0    0     1       0      0      1   1      0
```

---

If we want missing combinations, create a `factor` column with `levels` specified

```
colors <- factor(unlist(df1[-(1:2)]), levels = c("black", "blue", 
   "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "purple", "red", "yellow", "white"))
items <- df1$item[row(df1[-c(1:2)])]
table(items, colors)
```

-output

```
    colors
items black blue gray green magenta orange purple red yellow white
    1     0    1    0     0       0      0      0   2      0     0
    2     0    1    0     0       0      0      0   0      0     0
    3     0    0    0     1       0      0      0   1      1     0
    4     1    0    0     0       1      1      1   2      1     0
    5     0    0    0     1       0      0      1   1      0     0
```